# Modify headers on Alamofire request before it is resume()d

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am creating Alamofire requests with `startRequestsImmediately` set to false. I then enqueue a block onto an NSOperationQueue which calls `resume()` on the request. If I need to suspend outgoing requests, I simply suspend the queue and let them buffer up. Once I unsuspend the queue, any requests are dispatched.

Sometimes, while the queue is suspended, I need to change a header on any existing requests in there (e.g. an authorization token). I have not found a way to do this (anything I try isn't taking effect). Is it possible with NSURLSessionTask? Is it possible to swap out the NSURLSessionTask for a given request (with updated headers)?

Comment: Did you manage to find a way on that ?

Comment: Yes and no. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the `Alamofire.Request` is created, it creates an `NSURLSessionTask` under the hood and once created, that is effectively read-only. So the only option I've found is to defer creation of the `Request` until my request is about to be run.

However, the `Request` object is what you set up response handlers on. For example, the client wants to call something like: `request().response(...).response(...)`. Alamofire's `request()` returns the `Request` object on which you can call `response()` multiple times in order to setup the response handlers which will run once the request is finished. But if you need to defer the creation of the `Request` until you know it's about to run - so that you can use the latest headers at that time - how do you return it to the clients so that they can call `.response()` on it?

The way I've done it is to create a `myRequest()` wrapper (instead of being able to override the actual `request()` function/name) on my `Alamofire.Manager`-derived class, which takes 1 additional parameter - a 'request ready' block (which itself takes an `Alamofire.Request`) and instead of returning the `Request` from `myRequest()`, `myRequest()`, returns nothing, but calls the block (passing it the `Request`) just as the request is about to be dispatched.

So something like

`manager.request(.GET, "endpoint").responseJSON(…)`

instead becomes

```
manager.myRequest(.GET, "endpoint") { request in
    request.responseJSON(...)
}
```

In this way I can defer creation of the `Alamofire.Request` (which immediately creates the underlying `NSURLSessionTask` and locks in the headers as they are at that moment) until later, while not inconveniencing the client too much in how they specify the response handlers.

`myRequest()` looks like this (not including app-specific stuff):

```
func myRequest(
    method: Alamofire.Method,
    _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
    parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil,
    requestReady: ((Request) -> Void)?) {

    pendingRequestsQueue.addOperationWithBlock { [weak self] in
        if let strongSelf = self {
            let request = strongSelf.request(method, URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)

            if let requestReady = requestReady {
                requestReady(request)
            }

            request.resume()
        }
    }
}
```